# Selecting containers like in Firefox debug tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm trying to create container selector like the one if Firefox's debug tools (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). The general idea is to return the list of selected (clicked) elements for further processing.

Here's what I have now:

http://jsfiddle.net/jEHBU/

```
$('ul,li,a').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({
        outline: "1px solid red"
    });
}).on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!$(this).hasClass('box-selected')) {
        $(this).css({
            outline: 0
        });
    }
}).on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if ($(this).hasClass('box-selected')) {
        $(this.removeClass('box-selected'))
            .css({
            outline: 0
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('box-selected').
        css({
            outline: '1px solid green'
        });
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```

Works in simplests cases, but the general problem is event bubbling,
and the selection interface is not very friendly.

How it is done in Firefox? Maybe it needs a better styling? What about the tooltips?

Answer (score 0):

It is not bubbling. The problem is that when you `mouseenter` an anchor you also `mouseenter` ul and li on the way (sometimes).
You can try to *uncheck* all parents when an element is `mouseenter`ed

```
$('ul,li,a').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css({
        outline: "1px solid red"
    });
    $(this).parents().each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            outline: 0
        });
    });
});
```

To make the code more clean you can assign a class instead of adding/removing `outline` property every time.

Here's update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEHBU/8/

**EDIT**:
I slightly changed the fiddle above. It was removing the outline from parent elements even if they were highlighted by click.